# Update Datetime column in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

For some reason this command isn't working and can't figure out what might be wrong. I'm using mysql and this is the command:

```
update users set regdate = '2017-06-30 15:08:24' where regdate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

and this is the error message

```
Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'regdate' at row 1
```

The regdate field is datetime type.
Please help

Comment: How can  a day or month be zero?

Comment: Why don't you store such dates as NULL values?

Comment: Please post `SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;`

Comment: @lad2025 Thanks, here is the output: 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'

Comment: `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_Z‌​ERO_DATE` there's your answer

Comment: @RealCheeseLord Yup exactly, feel free to post an answer :)

Comment: @RealCheeseLord so how do I update all those fields then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @lad2025 for asking the right questions.
To Change those Settings you can use:

```
SET SQL_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_D‌​IVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_A‌​UTO_CREATE_USER,NO_E‌​NGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

enter that line before your `UPDATE` and no Errors should occur

if I understand the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_in_date) correctly this will not set the SQL_mode permanently. For permanent Changes you will have to modify your .cnf file

Comment: Guys, I'm getting a little confused now. I just want to update that field..but with a few complex suggestions here I'm beginning to feel like my head is spinning. :(

Comment: the other answer will enable you to enter `NULL` values as your datetime. this should enable you to enter `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Comment: @HelenNeely I added additional explanation to my answer.

Comment: @RealCheeseLord Thanks, I could not run your command, here is the error: Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'ERROR_FOR_D‌​IVISION_BY_ZERO'

Comment: hmmm, weird, since it was already set in your Output, but just try removing that part from the command and be careful not to divide by Zero... from documentation: `If this mode is not enabled, division by zero inserts NULL and produces no warning`

Comment: could be your Version of mysql no longer supports that command on its own, but activates it with `STRICT` mode

Comment: The version of the mysql installed does not support it. Thanks, this has been a lesson for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't store such dates. What sense does it make to you, to have such dates (wasting space) in your DB?

Instead make your column nullable and store `NULL` instead of `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`.

Change your column definition with

```
ALTER TABLE your_tablename MODIFY COLUMN your_columnname datetime NULL;
```

The sql_modes you have set there are a good idea, they simply prevent having rubbish in your database. I wouldn't change them.

The only "negative" aspect is, that you have to adjust your queries a little bit. The `NULL` "value" is not a value at all, it's literally "no value" (that's why you will save some space). Therefore, when you want to find such dates you can't do

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE datetime_column = NULL;
```

You have to use the special comparison operator like

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE datetime_column IS NULL;
```

But that's not really a problem. The other approach of changing the sql_mode is "being more comfy but a bit more dangerous".

Comment: Will the new modification not see all other valid dates in that field to NULL? Sorry just scared :(

Comment: No, it won't (removed the NOT in there, was a typo). It will simply allow NULL values. It won't change data.